# jQuery Change Event causes Tabselect event not to fire

Tags: jquery

I have an input box on the screen and jquery UI.tabs. When I put something into the input box and then click on a tab. I want a change event to happen and then load up the new tab. What is happening is the change event is triggered BUT the tabselect event is not. here is my code for both the change and tabselect:

```
$("#tabs").bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
    if (changeSelectedTab()) {
        selectedTab = ui.index;
        LoadForSelectedTab();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

$("#tabs").tabs('select', tab);

$('#BillOfLading_Number').change(function(event) {
    ChangeBOLNumber(true);
});
```

What am i doing wrong? If i blank out the change event the tabselect fires if I put any thing inside the change event it will not fire. I am using IE 8.

thanks in advance

A little more detail:
If I do:

```
$('#BillOfLading_Number').change(function(event) {
    //ChangeBOLNumber(true);
});
```

it works.

But if I do:

```
$('#BillOfLading_Number').change(function(event) {
    return true;
});
```

it does not work.

**The answer** but it brings up another question. The function ChangeBOLNumber(true); was triggering an ajax call and that was messing up the events. If I make the ajax call synchronous everything works. But I don't like doing that cause that seems bad to me. So the new question is does any one know why ajax does that and how to fix it without making it synchronous?

Comment: Are there any errors appearing in the console being caused by the code in `ChangeBOLNumber()`?

Comment: I suspect there is some error inside `ChangeBOLNumber`.

Comment: What does the `changeSelectedTab()` function do?

Answer (score 1):

Check the console in the browser. My guess would be that your `ChangeBOLNumber()` function is causing an error which stops code execution, thus preventing the `tabselect` event from firing.

Comment: So that was a thought of mine so I changed my code to look like:

    $('#BillOfLading_Number').change(function(event) {
        return true;
    });
and it did the same thing.